# Django JS Internationalization doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization, gettext

I have a problem with djangojs translation. When doing `makemessages -d djangojs -l tr` it works: it get all the strings where `gettext` is called. But when it comes to translation in the page load, it doesn't work. I used JqueryDialog and I'm trying to translate the buttons of the modal box. My code is below:

```
window.id_agreement_modal = $("#id_agreement_modal");

var buttons_trans  = {};
var sb = gettext("Submit(Saves locally, not in DB)");
buttons_trans[sb] = function() {
                $("#id_agreement").html(window.id_agreement_modal.val());
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                window.opened = false;
            };

var cl = gettext("Close");
buttons_trans[cl] = function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                window.opened = false;
            };

window.id_agreement_modal.dialog({
    resizable: true, 
    width: 700,
    height: 500,
    modal: true,
    open: function(){
        $(this).html($("#id_agreement").val());
    },
    close: function(){
        window.opened = false;
    },
    buttons: buttons_trans,
    autoOpen: false
});
```

I added `{% load i18n %}` on every template and I'm loading the code above from external JS - after loading the `i18n` library. But it seems like the gettext is not defined, when I try to evaluate it in the Chrome console. There are bunch of iframes in the page, I'm pretty sure that I included the library in all of them.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add your translations to the .po file? Is there any #fuzzy tag in it? Have you compiled the messages using `compilemessages`?

Comment: Yep, I've done all of those ;) And I realized that the .mo binaries are also changed after compiling the .po (with js translations in it). I assume it has the serialized version of the js translations but I'm very confused about it, after seeing it not working when loading the template. ;)